# Scrolling the terminal with vi shortcuts?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, scrolling

I have vi shortcuts set on my gnome-terminal and can't figure out how to scroll through the terminal's output after the change. Before I could use Shift+Page-up, but this isn't working in normal or insert mode. I'm also using tmux.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about terminal key bindings and not the Vi family of editors.

Answer (score 3):

In tmux you can use `prefix+[` to [enable scrolling](https://superuser.com/questions/209437/how-do-i-scroll-in-tmux), which allows you to scroll inside your pane using vim bindings. Use `q` to exit this mode.

Comment: This isn't working in the way I was expecting. I see only movement of the cursor with the arrow keys, and g or f shortcuts. No ctrl+e, ctrl+y, ctrl+f, or ctrl+b. and the g shortcut is odd.

Comment: @Hussar That's because it's really tmux with vim support, not vim itself that's doing the scrolling. Which makes sense, vim is 'just' and editor but tmux actually deal with panes and windows. See the `tmux` `man` pages and search for 'copy mode' for all the vi bindings that are supported. An excerpt is given in the link in the answer.